# Convert cell array columns into matrix columns

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array (16x5) and I would like to extract all the values held in each column of the cell array and place them into a column within a matrix such that the columns are preserved (i.e. new matrix column for each cell array column).

What is the best way to do this?

I have tried:

```
for k=1:Samples
data(k,:) = [dist{:,k}];
end
```

But this returns the error

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

However I am not sure why.

EDIT - Cell array structure:
[image]

Comment: What is the content of your cell array elements (scalars, double arrays, etc)?

Comment: How can you check the data type of a cell array? 'whos' only defines it as a cell. I've updated the OP to include a screenshot of the cell array.

Comment: The output must be a cell array, right? Because otherwise those irregular shaped cell elements won't fit into a numeric array. And if, the output has to be a cell array, then it would  be a `1 x 5` sized cell array, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your loop code is valid, I assume the error is being raised because `data` is preallocated with dimensions not matching the length of the comma-expanded `dist` column (Matlab will grow matrices with explicit indices but not with the `:` operator).
You just need to get the length of the data after the comma-separated expansion:

```
nElem   = numel([dist{:,1}]);
Samples = size(dist,2);
data    = zeros(Samples,nElem);  
for k=1:Samples
  data(k,:) = [dist{:,k}];
end
```

Or if you want it in columns

```
data = zeros(nElem,Samples);  
for k=1:Samples
  data(:,k) = [dist{:,k}]';
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This was perfect and very insightful.